# Как обновить одно поле в таблице SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Привет. 
Встал вопрос... Как обновить только одно поле в таблице SQLite - Android.
Обновлять всю запись слишком много лишнего кода...

Comment: добавить в update условие, что бы выбрать эту запись?

Comment: Простите, я задумался и написал "запись", мне необходимо обновить лишь одно поле в записи.
Да, как условие правильно составить? 
Я обновляю всю запись так:
 - db.update("mytable", cv, "id = ?", new String[] {id});

в "cv" находятся данные для всех полей в виде пар (имя столбца - значение).... Такой подход не годится для обновления лишь 1 поля...

Comment: В ContentValues необходимо добавить лишь значение для одного поля.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например:

```
  String sql = "update mytable set sended = 1 where _id =" + recordid + ";" ;
  db.execSQL(sql);
```